# Quickest way to go from plain javascript to react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a project in plain js using vis js library and I need to migrate it to react. Can I just include my old js file and the vis js library and put the html file in the app.js of react ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could give it a try by [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html) way, which shows how to add `reactjs` to websites. The issue you will face could be spaghetti code and you may have a challenge adding JSX.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).